# I have a uitableview which has dynamic cells and when i scroll it then in some of the cells simpletext in a uitextview is detected as a link

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextview

**www.facebook.com** is a link but **heyday** is just a text and it is being displayed as a link

I have a `UITableView` which has dynamic cells and when i scroll it then in some of the cells, simple text in a `UITextView` is detected as a link.

see screen shot below.

[image]

Comment: can you post tableview cell code

Answer (score 0):

{

```
if person.valueForKey("type") as? String == Content_Type.CONTENT_TYPE_AUDIO
            {
                let cellIdentifier = "senderAudio"
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SenderAudioTableViewCell
                cellHeight[indexPath.row] = "Audio"
                cell.audioContent.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                if NSData(contentsOfFile: (person.valueForKey("lurl") as? String)!) != nil
                {
                    cell.senderAudioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_play_circle_outline_2x.png"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                    cell.senderAudioButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_stop_2x.png"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)

                    cell.senderAudioButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
                    self.audioDict[indexPath.row] = (person.valueForKey("lurl") as? String)!
                    cell.senderAudioButton.tag = indexPath.row
                }
                else
                {
                    SocketClient.updateLurlForCorruptImage((person.valueForKey("lurl") as? String)!, mid: (person.valueForKey("id") as? String)!)

                }
                var messagetime = (person.valueForKey("tim") as? String)!
                messagetime = messagetime.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\Optional[(](\\w+)[)]", withString: "$1", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: Range<String.Index> (start: messagetime.startIndex, end: messagetime.endIndex))
                let timeinterval = Double(messagetime)
                let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeinterval!/1000)
                cell.audioSentTimeLabel.text = SocketClient.getLocalTimeWithAMPM(date)
                cell.audioSentTimeLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 171/255, green: 172/255, blue: 172/255, alpha: 1.0)

                if person.valueForKey("mst") as? String == "1"
                {
                    cell.audioSentStatus.image = UIImage(named: "mesagesingletick-01.png")
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.audioSentStatus.image = UIImage(named: "mesageloading-01.png")
                }

                cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
                cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

                return cell
            }

            else
            {
                let cellIdentifier = "senderMessage"
                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SenderMessageTableViewCell

                cell.messageContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
                var messagetime = (person.valueForKey("tim") as? String)!
                messagetime = messagetime.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\\Optional[(](\\w+)[)]", withString: "$1", options: NSStringCompareOptions.RegularExpressionSearch, range: Range<String.Index> (start: messagetime.startIndex, end: messagetime.endIndex))
                let timeinterval = Double(messagetime)
                let date = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: timeinterval!/1000)
                cell.timeLabel.text = SocketClient.getLocalTimeWithAMPM(date)
                cell.timeLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 171/255, green: 172/255, blue: 172/255, alpha: 1.0)

                if person.valueForKey("mst") as? String == "1"
                {
                    cell.messageSendingStatus.image = UIImage(named: "mesagesingletick-01.png")
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.messageSendingStatus.image = UIImage(named: "mesageloading-01.png")
                }

                cell.messageTextview.text = person.valueForKey("body") as? String
                cell.messageTextview.sizeToFit()
                cellHeight[indexPath.row] = cell.messageTextview.frame.height
                cell.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
                cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

                return cell

            }
```

}